# UPDATE no MySql com base na última data de uma coluna

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando atualizar uma tabela no MySql (campo status da tabela Cliente) com base na última data em que este cliente foi visitado (campo dataAgendamento da tabela Agendamento), passando como parâmetro a quantidade de dias que definirá a mudança do status do mesmo (campo diasAtencao da tabela Cliente).

Porém um mesmo cliente possui diversas visitas, e eu precisaria verificar a mais recente, e com base nesta última visita, contar a quantidade de dias que o cliente não é visitado.

Consigo obter através do SELECT todos os clientes e suas respectivas datas mais atualizadas, porém não consigo atualizar os mesmos, pois não consigo comparar a data mais recente (A.dataAgendada) com uma lista de datas.

Já tentei utilizar o LIMIT 1, porém ele retorna apenas o primeiro elemento da consulta inteira, e não o primeiro elemento (data mais recente) de cada cliente.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
UPDATE Cliente C INNER JOIN Agendamento A ON C.idCliente = A.idCliente
SET C.status = 'Alerta'
WHERE DATEDIFF(now(), A.dataAgendada) >= C.diasAtencao

AND A.dataAgendada = (
 SELECT A.dataAgendada FROM(
 SELECT MAX(Ag.dataAgendada) as agg FROM CLIENTE Cli INNER JOIN AGENDAMENTO Ag ON Cli.IDCLIENTE = Ag.IDCLIENTE
 GROUP BY Cli.idCliente
 ORDER BY Ag.dataAgendada DESC

 ) as Consulta
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá tentou fazer assim

```
UPDATE 
   Cliente C 
SET 
   C.status = 'Alerta'
WHERE
  EXISTS(
         SELECT 
            A.dataAgendada
         FROM 
           Agendamento A 
         WHERE 
           C.idCliente = A.idCliente
           AND DATE(A.dataAgendada) = DATE(NOW())
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

desculpe pela demora no retorno. Kurole, sua resposta me ajudou a encontrar a solução para o meu problema, obrigado.

Segue solução abaixo:

```
UPDATE Cliente C SET C.status = 'Alerta' WHERE (SELECT (DATEDIFF(now(), MAX(A.dataAgendada))) FROM Agendamento A WHERE A.idCliente = C.idCliente) > C.diasAtencao");
```